# Bootstrap Textfield Autocomplete

Tags: html, symfony, textfield

So recently I created a new log in form using Bootstrap. All is working well. I am able to submit and log in successfully.

However, in my old site, I whenever I key in the first alphabet of my email, it shows a dropdown of all the emails starting with that alphabet that I previously entered and I can select my email instead of typing it all down.

But this is not available on my new site and I have no idea why. I built my new site using Symfony2 and Bootstrap. My old site is just plain PHP.

How can I get back that function? I tried adding autocomplete="on" but it does not help.

Comment: Which browser? Which doctype (HTML5)?